# Changing a decimal format

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\HP8200\\Desktop\\teste.txt"))
{            
    string numcont = _transaction.PartyFederalTaxID;
    double numenc = _transaction.BillToPartyID;
    double numfatura = _transaction.TransDocNumber;
    DateTime data = _transaction.CreateDate;
    double valor = _transaction.TotalAmount;
    short zona = transaction.Zone.ZoneID;
    //ean mal
    string ean = transaction.ATDocCodeId;
    double iva = 23;
    //preçoantesdisc mal
    double precoantesdisc = _transaction.TotalPaymentDiscountAmount;
    double preconet = transaction.Details.TotalAdvancementNetAmount;
    double quantidade = transaction.Details.Count;
    double bonus = _transaction.TotalPaymentDiscountAmount;            

    writer.WriteLine($"{numcont};{numenc};{numfatura};{data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")};{valor};{zona}{Environment.NewLine}{ean}{iva};{precoantesdisc};{preconet};{quantidade};{bonus}");
}
MessageBox.Show("saved");
```

And the variable `valor` is separating the decimal number with a "," and I need to do it with a "." Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `valor` is of type `double`, it doesn't use a decimal separator, only 
formatted strings have. The interpolated string converts it and it uses your current culture by default. You can use:

```
string valorStr = valor.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string line = $"{numcont};{numenc};{numfatura};{data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")};{valorStr};{zona}{Environment.NewLine}{ean}{iva};{precoantesdisc};{preconet};{quantidade};{bonus}";
writer.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct culture acording to your locale and use the ToString method:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");

writer.WriteLine($"{numcont};{numenc};{numfatura};{data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")};{valor.ToString(culture)};{zona}{Environment.NewLine}{ean}{iva};{precoantesdisc};{preconet};{quantidade};{bonus}");
```

Replace "es-ES" with the correct culture identifier (es-ES uses comma but better use your own, I suppose it's pt-BR).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @joaocosta I read your question reversed... the correct answer is the one from Tim, I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do so you have to make this :

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
```

Which will set `NumberDecimalSeparator` for the `CurrentCulture` to `"."`.

Then just use `ToString` method like such :

```
valor.toString("N", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
```

---

Downsides of this method is that you'll override the default `NumberDecimalSerpator` for the `CurrentCulture`. So if you do care about that you can just create a new `NumberFormatInfo` :

```
var nfiOrg = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
var nfiNew = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
nfiNew.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."
nfiNew.NativeDigits = nfiOrg.NativeDigits;
// set all of the other fields of nfiNew
```

And then use it in `ToString` call :

```
valor.toString("N", nfiNew);
```